# The files .DS_Store and .DS_Store had a tree conflict error from Git in xcode 8

Tags: git, xcode8

I'm using GitHub as project repository for ios project. But whenever I'm trying to pull project from xcode 8 I'm getting the following error:

> The files .DS_Store and .DS_Store had a tree conflict

Any solution?

Comment: You need to exclude them from git.

Comment: `.DS_Store` is a hidden file created by macOS Finder for its own usage. It is not of any use to put it into the repository.

Comment: Done.Deleted all .DS_Store file from Git and then pulled.Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

.DS_Store is a file that Mac makes to index folders. These are automatically created files and keeps on changing.

Even if you deleted it from Git and download again, you would, in future, start getting the same error because next time you commit and push, a new .DS_Store file will be at git remote.

What you need to do it to start ignoring these files. You will have to mention about these files in .gitignore file.

You can create .gitignore file by executing `touch .gitignore` 
This command will create gitignore file, which you can open and just write `.DS_Store` and save the file. Henceforth, git will start ignoring this file in commits.